# How to remove line break if line character count less than n chars

Tags: sed, awk, perl

I need to concatenate the line with next line if the line char count is less than x chars.

Comment: welcomme to U&L. Can you edit your post with what you have tried ?

Comment: can be improved: `awk 'length < 3 { printf "%s ", $0; next }1' file`

Comment: And if after concatenation, the line is still less than x chars, do you want to concatenate the next line again?

Comment: Yes. We have to check the length of the line after concatenation to make sure all the lines have the same length.
The file should be a fixed width (each record should be fit in a single file) but, sometimes the single record spanned into multiple lines due to bad data (new line characters in data ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU sed

Input

```
flood
good
good
good
good
good
flood
good
good
```

If you want the newly concatenated line to count against the number of chars

```
sed ':;/.\{5,\}$/!{N;s/\n/ /g;b}'

flood
good good
good good
good flood
good good
good
```

If you want to count each line on its own and concatenate each line that is less to the previous

```
sed ':;/[^\n]\{5,\}$/!{N;$!b};s/\n/ /g'

flood
good good good good good flood
good good good
```

Comment: That is GNU specific. `:` requires a label. And traditional implementations (and the current version of the POSIX spec) allow any char in the label name (so `:;/...` would define a label called `;/...`). `b` without a label is meant to branch to the end. `[^\n]` matches anything but backslash and `n` in most `sed` implementations. `}` and `b` cannot be followed by any other command.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas There you go :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ n=20
$ seq 40 | sed -e :1 -e "/.\{$n\}/!{N;s/\n//;b1" -e '}'
123456789101112131415
16171819202122232425
26272829303132333435
3637383940
```

Or to join lines so that they are *up to* 20 chars (as opposed to at least 20 chars):

```
$ seq 40 | fmt -w 20
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30 31 32
33 34 35 36 37 38
39 40

$ seq 40 | par -w20
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31
32 33 34 35 36 37 38
39 40
```

Comment: Isn't the second keeping lines under a certain number of chars, rather than ensuring they they are at least that many ?

Comment: @User112638726, yes, I guess I should that make clear.